# How to change post value in each iterarion of foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I need to change the post value on each iteration of foreach loop. Here is my code:

```
foreach ($amovess as $key => $val) {
    $actions = $amovess[$key];
    $lastid = $database->insert("tablename", [
        "Action" => $actions,
        "barcode"=>$data['barcode1txt'],
        "barcode"=>$data['barcode2txt']
    ]);
}
```

I want that on first move of foreach loop `$data['barcode1txt']` should insert and on second move `$data['barcode2txt']` should insert. Please guide me.

Comment: What is `$key` on your iterations? Maybe `'barcode'=>$data['barcode' . ($key + 1) . ' txt']`

Comment: In $key ,I am getting my options value from down in array form. <option value="Checkin:Checkout" id="Exchange"><?php _e('Exchange'); ?></option> this values Checkin and Checkout .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know what is your key value coming . you can do like this

```html
<?php

    $i =1;
    foreach ($amovess as $key => $val) { 
        $actions = $amovess[$key];
        $lastid = $database->insert("tablename", [
                    "Action" => $actions,
                    "barcode" => $data['barcode' . $i . 'txt']
                ]);
        $i++;
    }

?>
```